# Mongo DB connections are not getting closed,While using reactive spring boot infinite streams

Tags: spring, mongodb, reactive-programming

I am using Reactive Spring Boot (Flux) for infinite streams and @Tailable in a Reactive Mongo Repository to enable server side events. For each request to the Flux controller, it is creating a brand new MongoDB connection, although I am using the reactive Mongo client to create the connection. Because of this after 100 connections the application is throwing a MongoDB connection timeout exception. Below is my code.

**REST Controller** [image: REST Controller]

**Reactive Mongo Repository :**[image: Reactive Mongo Repository]

Please advise, if anyone knows how to fix this!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please don't add links to code instead include them in your question. Please edit your question to include the code/config.

Comment: Thank you..I tried to add images.but it is not allowing me to add because i am new to stack overflow.

Comment: You should add code as text using the proper code/formatting tags, instead of screenshots. The latter becomes unreadable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and use that to improve your question,

Comment: Hi @AkhileshReddy , did you manage to find some way to handle this? Thanks